# API and web scraping

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I am trying to access the contents on text files on the [page](https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/c821gj76b?locale=en&page=2#release-items). Since each text file has a different url, I am unable to generate urls in python and **scrape** the content using Pandas. Therefore, I was trying to use the [API](https://usda.library.cornell.edu/apidoc/index.html#/account/getUserToken) for this. When I execute for user token, I get something like this:

```py
{
  "jwt": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjU5MDR9.b9elxkmNj0kmWxDPjal0_mLY9UPg7enoT7Cdg7gN1d0"
}
```

Now, I am not sure how to use this to get access to all the text files on the first page I mentioned above. Can someone guide me on how to progress?

Comment: The swagger docs indicate that the api-token must be passed as a Bearer in the Authorization header. So, set a header like "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0ex..."

Comment: Do you need this token after all? You can select all links that end with `.txt` with BeautifulSoup and download them with `requests`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I was thinking the same. However, I guess I cant automate the generate of url in this case. There would be more than 200 urls that I will have to open. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @RobertStiffler Can you elaborate? Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge on the use of APIs

Comment: @RaghavGoyal Depends for what information are you searching for. For the latest document?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have to extract information on prices for each month from 1990 to 2019.

Comment: Then, in my opinion, it's better to download all files and extract the information from them locally.

Comment: @RaghavGoyal whatever library you are using to make HTTP requests should have a way of specifying headers. You need to add an `Authorization` header on each request made to the API.

Comment: @RaghavGoyal But on second thinking, maybe with API you will got the information in structured format. I see that for older years the data are only in PDF form.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yeah, initially I am planning to extract data from only text files. Do you know how to use API?

Comment: @RaghavGoyal Unfortunately not, I don't have experience with this API. But I can post a script that will select all `.txt` links from the page and download them - if you want.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yeah, if you can, that would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will go from the page 1 to the last page and select all links that end with `.txt`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

base_url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu'

url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/c821gj76b?locale=en&page=1#release-items'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

page = 1
while True:
    print('Page no.{}...'.format(page))
    print('-' * 80)

    txt_urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('#release-items a[href$=".txt"]')]
    pprint(txt_urls)

    m = soup.select_one('a[rel="next"][href]')
    if m and m['href'] != '#':
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + m['href']).text, 'html.parser')
        page += 1
    else:
        break
```

Prints:

```
Page no.1...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
['https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/kd17d5288/ms35tm800/agpr0719.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/r494vw17c/q524jz702/agpr0619.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/bc386t90p/vx021r07n/agpr0519.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/3484zr667/4j03d7561/agpr0419.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/f7623m42k/qf85nk40w/agpr0319.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/7w62fg32b/n009w815n/agpr0219.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/kk91fs55d/z890s0860/agpr0219.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/t435gj88z/8910k0903/agpr0119.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/m613n410w/41687p68x/01-30-19_Report_Reschedule_ASB_Notice_Final.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/st74cv012/0z709086s/agpr1118.txt']
Page no.2...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
['https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/5q47rs05x/m900nx65x/agpr1018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/4b29b953w/m900nx64n/agpr0918.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/5h73px257/1c18dh137/AgriPric-08-29-2018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/t722hb16b/76537257b/AgriPric-07-30-2018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/pz50gx32d/qb98mg88k/AgriPric-06-28-2018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/vd66w115f/p2676w80r/AgriPric-05-30-2018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/9c67wp20r/bc386k622/AgriPric-04-27-2018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/r494vm201/h128ng14d/AgriPric-03-28-2018.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/z316q273n/37720f04c/AgriPric-02-27-2018_correction.txt',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/5d86p1433/zp38wd92f/AgriPric-01-30-2018.txt']

...and so on.
```

---

You can download a text file using these links, e.g.:

```
txt_data = requests.get('https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/c821gj76b/kd17d5288/ms35tm800/agpr0719.txt').text
print(txt_data)
```

Prints (but you can save it to the file instead of printing to the screen):

```
Agricultural Prices

ISSN: 1937-4216

Released July 31, 2019, by the National Agricultural Statistics Service 
(NASS), Agricultural Statistics Board, United States Department of 
Agriculture (USDA).

June Prices Received Index Up 1.0 Percent 

...etc.
```

Comment: @AndrejKesley Thanks for this. I am trying to understand the code. The code extracts data up till page 7, however, there are text files on pages after that as well. Why is it so? Also, where are the urls being stored. Is it in the txt_urls variable? It actually prints an empty list.

Comment: @RaghavGoyal Running code here I get `.txt` links from page 1 till page 34. After that it's only PDF links. In this script I don't store the urls, only print them at screen. You can use these URLS and donwload the txt files to disk, for example.

Comment: I stored them like this:
```python
txt_urls = []
``` 
and then,
```python
txt_urls.append([a["href"] for a in soup.select('#release-items a[href$=".txt"]')])
```
But it stores a list for each page. As in, txt_urls[0] contains urls from page 1. Is there a better way in which each list index corresponds to a single url?